# How to alias an interface method implementation with Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I'm using `Mono.Cecil` (version 0.6.9.0) to alias a method that implements an interface method. To do that, I have to add an `Override` to the target method that points back to the interface method (much like what's possible with VB.NET), like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Mono.Cecil;

class Program {

  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var asm = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    var source = asm.MainModule.Types["A"];
    var sourceMethod = source.Methods[0];
    var sourceRef = new MethodReference(
      sourceMethod.Name,
      sourceMethod.DeclaringType,
      sourceMethod.ReturnType.ReturnType,
      sourceMethod.HasThis,
      sourceMethod.ExplicitThis,
      sourceMethod.CallingConvention);

    var target = asm.MainModule.Types["C"];
    var targetMethod = target.Methods[0];
    targetMethod.Name = "AliasedMethod";
    targetMethod.Overrides.Add(sourceRef);

    AssemblyAssert.Verify(asm); // this will just run PEVerify on the changed assembly
  }

}

interface A {
  void Method();
}

class C : A {
  public void Method() { }
}
```

What I'm getting is a `PEVerify.exe` error that indicates that my class doesn't implement the interface method anymore. It seems that there's a token mismatch in the changed assembly between the override reference and the method in the interface:

```
[MD]: Error: Class implements interface but not method (class:0x02000004; interface:0x02000002; method:0x06000001). [token:0x09000001]
```

I know that if I use the `MethodDefinition` directly it will work:

```
targetMethod.Overrides.Add(sourceMethod);
```

But I really need to use a `MethodReference` because I might have generic parameters and arguments in the types involved, and a simple `MethodDefinition` won't do.

**Update**: As recommended by [Jb Evain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240150/how-to-alias-an-interface-method-implementation-with-mono-cecil/3240249#3240249), I've [migrated](http://wiki.github.com/jbevain/cecil/migration) to version 0.9.3.0. But, the same error still happens. Here's the migrated code:

```
var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var source = module.GetType("A");
var sourceMethod = source.Methods[0];

var sourceRef = new MethodReference(
  sourceMethod.Name,
  sourceMethod.ReturnType) {
    DeclaringType = sourceMethod.DeclaringType,
    HasThis = sourceMethod.HasThis,
    ExplicitThis = sourceMethod.ExplicitThis,
    CallingConvention = sourceMethod.CallingConvention 
};

var target = module.GetType("C");
var targetMethod = target.Methods[0];
targetMethod.Name = "AliasedMethod";
targetMethod.Overrides.Add(sourceRef);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the annoyance of using the 0.6. You have to put the newly created MethodReference in the .MemberReferences collection of your module.

I strongly suggest you switch to 0.9.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I've tried that as well, and it didn't work.

Comment: I've just migrated it, and I get the same error. I'll update the question.

Comment: Jordão: it seems that it's a peverify bug to me. The method reference is properly emitted, but peverify doesn't like it.

If I use your exact scenario, but with a method on a generic type, it works just fine.

So it seems to me that you'll have to deal with it yourself, that is, putting the MethodDefinition if the method is not on a generic type and is defined in the current assembly, or you'll create a MethodReference.

Comment: Do you know of any programmatic way of verifying an assembly (maybe in the Mono project), without using PEVerify?

Comment: Cool, glad to know it works. As for verifying assemblies programmaticaly, there's no cross-platform way. All verifiers are usually very tied to the runtime. So if you're ok with it you can probably call unmanaged methods to do so. But I never went this far, and always resorted to call peverify on both .net and Mono.